# How to set "Referer" header in Angular universal Httpclient Xhr calls?

Tags: angular, express, xmlhttprequest, angular-universal, referer

I have an Angular Universal SSR app that gets data from the API server with HttpClient.
Everything works fine and I can Render data server-side.

The problem is I want to have client Referer which Browser Sets by default in CSR and sends data based on each site (I have multiple sites with different domains).

I get the referer with like this:

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
...

if (!this.isBrowser) {
  const serverRequest = this.injector.get(REQUEST) as Request;
  this.referer = `${serverRequest.protocol}://${serverRequest.get('Host')}`;
  console.log('refrerr is : ',this.referer) 
}
```

then I Set it in my header with:

```
request = req.clone({
    url: `${this.Config.url}${req.url}`,
    setHeaders: {
      referer: this.referer,
    },
    params
  });
```

But I get this err in the console :

> Refused to set unsafe header "referer"

Comment: this header isn't supposed to be set by javascript. it is automatically added by browser without any custom code

Comment: @Andrei thank you for answering. But I render my App on the Server-side and I don't know how to get which client is requesting data?

Comment: seems so. can this information be retrieved from access token ?

Comment: @Andrei no it's not related to user login or etc. I want the first content rendered to the client based on domain referral change. even bots and crawlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
npm install xhr2
```

Then in your `server.ts` file

```
import * as xhr2 from 'xhr2';

//...
xhr2.prototype._restrictedHeaders = {};
```